# Expression engine updates

Tags: ee2-upgrades

I have a client that needs an expression engine site updated in order to install an add-on. Does he have to buy it all over again? If not, His relationship with his previous developer isn't good so he doesn't have the login info for Ellis labs.  Would he be able to use a license number or something? I went to ask Ellis labs, but you have to pay for the privilege of speaking to someone there.

Comment: You can email EllisLab at sales@ellislab.com and they should be able to help you out.

Comment: EllisLab team is really accessible. You can write to any of them, if you have any problem that doesn't fit into "support" category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the license number of an EE Install log into the CPanel and go to Admin > General Configuration > License Number :: If you give that to ellis lab they should be able to get you taken care of.

EllisLab Contact Info:

Email: sales@ellislab.com

Twitter: @EllisLab